# Verify SAML response using x509 certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, saml

I am currently creating a function that will take in a SAML Response as an XMLDocument. I would then like to verify if this response is valid otherwise reject it.

```cs
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(samlXML);
XmlElement node = (XmlElement)samlXML.GetElementsByTagName("ds:SignatureValue")[0];
XmlElement certificate = (XmlElement)samlXML.GetElementsByTagName("ds:X509Certificate")[0];
signedXml.LoadXml(node);
bool passes = signedXml.CheckSignature(certificates, true);
```

When I run this I get the exception:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Malformed element Signature.
```

Comment: Another StackOverflow question [Verify signature on SAML assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394137/verify-signature-on-saml-assertion) provides valuable discussions and solutions on your question.

Comment: Have a look at [Sustainsys](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) or [Foxtec](https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2)